# Large image in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a large image (685 × 900, just 25kb in PNG) and what I need is to show it in the 'content' auto adjusted for the screen size and with the possibility of zoom it with the fingers.

Now, with:

```
<div data-role="content" id="results">
   <img src="img/myimg.png">
</div>
```

It shows the full image and I can't even move through it.
Is there anyway to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Without zoom: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfL50.png

Zoomed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpZV0.png

Comment: Load the image directly, without any HTML.

Comment: Well, the idea is to show it with some other things in the screen, not just the image.

Comment: Load the image directly into an iframe? It's not clear what you want the complete end result to be.

Comment: Something like lock the header and the footer, for example, and show the image auto adjusted in the middle for the screen. Maybe an iframe could work, I was looking if there was a more elegant solution, anyway I'm gonna try it. Thanks

Comment: I have added to examples. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem, you need to put this image as background and use the property `background-size: 100%`

Comment: No.. it isn't a background image. Just and image I want to show and want to give the possibility to zoom it. I have write the 'width' property to 100% and now it auto adjust to the screen (I still can't zoom it). The problem is that if I enter with my laptop it takes the 100% of the screen too and not just the 685x900.

Comment: Have you tried wrap the image?
`<div style="max-width: 685px;"><img src="youImage685x900.png" style="position: relative; width: 100%;" /></div>`

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions.

1. Use img { max-width: 100%;} in css style. This will force images to resize depending on the container’s size. But a problem here is with mobile devices. They still download the big picture, although they see it resized. This is often a problem in terms of speed for mobile devices. Also, please see the video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DvIOex3BhD8
2. Use the addon: http://www.concrete5.org/marketplace/addons/picturefill-image/ With the help of it you can make different images show up at different resolutions (for tablets, phone screens), so you don’t have to deal only with automatically resized pictures.

Both of the solutions are only needed when you have a responsive website.

Images take spaces that they were given. They will take the whole screen width if their containers take it. And they will take half a screen if their container spans only half a screen.